# which is better Bootstrap or Google Polymer

Tags: web, twitter-bootstrap-3, polymer

Can anyone give a brief comparison for Bootstrap Vs Polymer, Pros and cons for using it?? and which is best suited with angularjs

Answer (score 28):

`Bootstrap` and `Polymer` are two very different libraries that fulfill different purposes and have very different use cases.

Before you choose one over the other you need to first understand what they both really are.

#### Bootstrap:

- CSS library to makes styling website much easier
- Built using CSS and some JS
- Used only to style websites and web apps

#### Polymer:

- Provides a sugar coat on top of the Web-Components Api
- Written entirely on JS
- Used primarily to build web components
- Polymer Team has built some UI components used for building ui but it is not a styling framework.

You also mentioned to write some pros and cons of these libraries but to do so you need to compare two libraries that fit the same category, eg `BootStrap vs Foundation` or `Polymer vs [Some other web-components library]`.

**And finally answer to the final part of your question.**
Because BootStrap is just a framework to style html elements it can be used with nearly all MVC frameworks, but Polymer on the other hand is quite not compatible with Angular in particular because both Polymer and Angular have a very similar way to add directives which always result in conflicts.

Final Note:
Angular here refers to angular-2
If you have chosen `Polymer` for the material design aspect you can use `Angular-material` to style you `Angular` App

Comment: Good answer. May I ask what you would recommend with Polymer? Foundation, Bootstrap, or something else?

Comment: That's the best part about Polymer, you can literally use any css framework you are familiar with, I would recommended Foundation if you are building an App and Bootstrap is great for websites.

Comment: you can use polymer components in angular 2 with https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/using-polymer-components-in-angular-2